# Drupal 8 form and view in block

Tags: forms, view, block, drupal-8

I am very new Drupal, In a block I would like to have a form with select box and submit button. Each options in the link is link of content page. That is when the user select an option and click the submit button it will redirect to other node page.

For the above requirement client used Web Form for Drupal 7 and I would like to clone the requirement for Drupal 8. I tried EForm and I am able to create a form but I can not able to show the form in Block Layout and View.

I am not sure the module Eform is suitable for my requirement.
Can you guys please help me what modules do I need to install for the above requirement in Drupal 8.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain what you need it for with an example? Cause to me it sounds unnecessary complicated to use a form to just link to another page.

Comment: My requirement is very simple, there is a form with a select box and a button. The select box will have values as link of content page and the user select an option and click the button, then it load a page. For example, in a country drop down I have list of options like Asia, Australia, Europe, etc. If the user select a country then it will load appropriate country page. The option values must be managed (add country or edit country) from admin panel. Each country page in the select box is simple content page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I don't know if there are any modules out there which do exactly what you want to, but you can build your own custom solution. In my eyes there are two main possibilities:

- create a custom block type with a HTML body field, put your HTML in there and you're done. **Advantage**: easy to do, **Disadvantage**: hardcoded
- clean way: create a new node type and/or a new category, which you will use for your country nodes. Then you'll create a block programmatically and query for all nodes of that certain country type or for nodes with the "country page"-category, whatever you use to organize those nodes. Then you just create a form out of that data and render it.
  **Advantage**: dynamic, the select list will update itself whenever you add or delete new nodes of that type / category. **Disadvantage**: takes more effort initially

I personally would recommend using option 2. Option 1 is better for really simple and "stupid" requirements like showing some hardcoded text/image on several places on your site, or if it's something temporary like some campaign teaser, which will be over in 1 week and you'll throw it away after that.

EDIT:

Entity Query: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8

How to build Forms in Drupal 8:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2117411

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It will be more helpful if you recommend any tutorial for creating forms and querying in Drupal 8. :)

Comment: I've added two links which should help you. The first shows you how to query for entities (e.g. nodes), and the second how to build forms in Drupal 8. Just try it out, you should be able to build it :)

Comment: Nice tutorial, on form submit I would like to redirect the page to a node page of the content type, I tried $form_state->setRedirectUrl('node/1'); but it is not working. I don't have route config for the node page url so I am not sure how to redirect the page to node page with in the form module. Please help me.

Comment: It is working using this article - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AredirectForm/8

Answer (score 0):

For display only your block in your templates with preprocess the best way is:

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('my_block_id');
$variables['My_region'] = \Drupal::entityManager()
      ->getViewBuilder('block')
      ->view($block);
```

And in your page.html.twig or node.html.twig or xxx.html.twig use your variable My_region like this :

```
{% if page.My_region %}
{{ page.My_region }}
{% endif %}
```

For details check:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171686/how-can-i-programmatically-display-a-block